# Identifying character delimiter in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

Below is my data having with delimiter thorn þ

1þNaveenþ"Bangalore ,"Karnataka"þ

2þNaveenþ"Srikanth ^ Karnatakaþ562114

Create table statement is below

```
CREATE External TABLE adh_dev.delimiter_test (Number INT, Name STRING, 
Address string , Pincode int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\-61'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/xyz/test_delimiter';
```

Tried below approaches nothing worked

1) Followed below link
[Thorn character delimiter is not recognized in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245214/thorn-character-delimiter-is-not-recognized-in-hive)

2)Tried to put '-2'

3)Followed below link
http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-thorn-ascii-code-232.html

4)Tried to put '\xFE'

Please help me in resolving the issue

I am using cloudera CDH5.11.1 and hive 1.1.0

Please help me in resolving the issue struggling from past 3 days

Comment: I would parse the raw data using Pig/Spark, then load into Hive using different delimiter

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746425/delimit-hive-csvserde-table-on-hexadecimal

Comment: Tried but not luck . For only One thing I am closer that is with character '-\61', When I put this character as separator I am not getting last column remaining other fields are populated